# Why can I cd /root in a pod container even after specifying proper "securityContext"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, root

I have a helm chart with deployment.yaml having the following params:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.newAppName }}
    chart: {{ template "newApp.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{ .Values.deploymentName }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.numReplicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.newAppName }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.newAppName }}
      namespace:  {{ .Release.Namespace }}
      annotations:
        some_annotation: val
        some_annotation: val
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.podRoleName }}
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ENV_VAR1
          value: {{ .Values.env_var_1 }}
        image: {{ .Values.newApp }}:{{ .Values.newAppVersion }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["/opt/myDir/bin/newApp"]
        args: ["-c", "/etc/config/newApp/{{ .Values.newAppConfigFileName }}"]
        name: {{ .Values.newAppName }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.newAppTLSPort }}
          protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /v1/h
            port: {{ .Values.newAppTLSPort }}
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 20
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /v1/h
            port: {{ .Values.newAppTLSPort }}
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 20
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/config/newApp
          name: config-volume
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/config/metrics
          name: metrics-volume
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/version/container
          name: container-info-volume
          readOnly: true
      - name: {{ template "newAppClient.name" . }}-client
        image: {{ .Values.newAppClientImage }}:{{ .Values.newAppClientVersion }}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args: ["run", "--server", "--config-file=/newAppClientPath/config.yaml", "--log-level=debug", "/newAppClientPath/pl"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: newAppClient-files
          mountPath: /newAppClient-path
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Values.newAppConfigMapName }}
      - name: container-info-volume
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Values.containerVersionConfigMapName }}
      - name: metrics-volume
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Values.metricsConfigMapName }}
      - name: newAppClient-files
        configMap:
          name: {{ .Values.newAppClientConfigMapName }}
          items:
            - key: config
              path: config.yaml
```

This helm chart is consumed by Jenkins and then deployed by Spinnaker onto AWS EKS service.

A security measure that we ensure is that /root directory should be private in all our containers, so basically it should deny permission when a user tries to manually do the same after

> kubectl exec -it -n namespace_name pod_name -c container_name bash

into the container.

But when I enter the container terminal why can I still

> cd /root

inside the container when it is running as non-root?

**EXPECTED:** It should give the following error which it is not giving:

> cd root/
>
> bash: cd: root/: Permission denied

**OTHER VALUES THAT MIGHT BE USEFUL TO DEBUG:**
Output of *"ls -la"* inside the container:

> dr-xr-x---  1 root root    18 Jul 26 2021 root

*As you can see the r and x SHOULD BE UNSET for OTHER on root folder*

Output of *"id"* inside the container:

> bash-4.2$ id
> uid=1000 gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1000

**Using a helm chart locally to reproduce the error ->**

The same 3 securityContext params when used locally in a simple Go program helm chart yields the desired result.

Deployment.yaml of helm chart:

```
apiVersion: {{ template "common.capabilities.deployment.apiVersion" . }}
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 1000
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
```

Output of *ls -la* inside the container on local setup:

> drwx------   2 root root 4096 Jan 25 00:00 root

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  How do these Helm values get used?  What's the application code that's trying to change directories like that?

Comment: @DavidMaze Please review the question now, I have updated it with more details. As to specifically answer no application code is trying to change directories, its an actual user logging inside the container through bash and then changing the working directory to root.

Comment: Why do you think the permissions on `/root` shouldn't be 0550?  Why do you think your user shouldn't be a member of the root group?  Do you have any more source code beyond the boilerplate Helm chart fragment?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added the entire Helm chart for reference, maybe that might shed some light. 
And regarding the question that why the permissions on /root shouldn't be 0550?
Because the same params yield a permission of 700 on a container in local setup, so shouldn't the result be consistent even in the main setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can always cd into `/` in the UNIX system as non-root, so you can do it inside your container as well. However, e.g. creating a file there should fail with `Permission denied`.

Check the following.

```
# Run a container as non-root
docker run -it --rm --user 7447 busybox sh
# Check that it's possible to cd into '/'
cd /
# Try creating  file
touch some-file
touch: some-file: Permission denied
```

Comment: I actually want the root directory to be private.